Выведение значений на оси x на графике при помощью Matplotlib

Пробую построить bar chart с помощью matplotlib, но вместо указанных мной значений, перечисленных в переменной "Values" по оси x, на графике я получаю другие значения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом сделать так, чтобы на оси x были те значения, которые я указываю
Values = [0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7000000000000001, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]

Ginis = [0.5748595723557239, 0.6184584927676366, 0.6297867820308594, 0.6303391649806966, 0.6289648657934452, 0.6245963550986393, 0.6211358855275113, 0.6190743750967518, 0.6186210018586822, 0.6147599313491565]

plt.ylim(ymin = .95 * min(Ginis))
plt.ylim(ymax = 1.05 * max(Ginis))
plt.bar(Values, Ginis)
plt.show()


У вас значения по оси x меньше, чем ширина столбца по умолчанию. уменьшите ширину столбцов, либо увеличьте порядок значений x, тогда все получится:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Values = [0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7000000000000001, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]

Ginis = [0.5748595723557239, 0.6184584927676366, 0.6297867820308594, 0.6303391649806966, 0.6289648657934452, 0.6245963550986393, 0.6211358855275113, 0.6190743750967518, 0.6186210018586822, 0.6147599313491565]

plt.ylim(ymin = .95 * min(Ginis))
plt.ylim(ymax = 1.05 * max(Ginis))
plt.bar(Values, Ginis, width=.05) # <- здесь
plt.xticks(Values) # <- отображать все значения x
plt.show()


